# Getting NullpointerException While Printing Data from SharedPreference for first time in another activity

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

> Here is the code i am not getting any value in another activity from shared preference for first time even though json response is been saved in explorer but when i click the button for second time and go to that activity again i am getting the value but for the first time i am not getting any value please help thanks

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextInputEditText name, addresssss, address1111, city, state, country, postalcode, landmark,mobiles;
TextView namee, addresss, address11, cityy, statee, countryy, postalcodee, landmarkk,hhhh;
String nameee, nam, ad, ad1, ci, sta, cou, pos, land, nameeee;
Button Submit;
String ggg;
JSONObject object;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    namee = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.namee);
    landmarkk = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.landmarkk);
    addresss = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.addresss);
    address11 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.address11);
    cityy = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cityy);
    statee = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statee);
    countryy = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.countryy);
    postalcodee = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.postalcodee);
    hhhh=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.hhhh);
    mobiles=(TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.mobiles);
    name = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    addresssss = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.address);
    address1111 = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.address1);
    city = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.city);
    state = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.state);
    country = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.country);
    postalcode = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.postalcode);
    landmark = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.landmark);
    Submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Submit);
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new SendRequest().execute();
            nameee = name.getText().toString().trim();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name.getText().toString())) {


                return;


            }
            ad = addresssss.getText().toString();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(addresssss.getText().toString())) {


                return;

            }
            ad1 = address1111.getText().toString();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(address1111.getText().toString())) {


                return;

            }
            ci = city.getText().toString();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(city.getText().toString())) {


                return;

            }
            sta = state.getText().toString();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(state.getText().toString())) {


                return;

            }
            cou = country.getText().toString();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(country.getText().toString())) {


                return;

            }
           pos = postalcode.getText().toString();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(postalcode.getText().toString())) {


                return;

            }
            land = landmark.getText().toString().trim();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(landmark.getText().toString())) {


                return;

            }
            nameeee=mobiles.getText().toString().trim();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mobiles.getText().toString())) {


                return;

            }
            else {


                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }


        }
    });
}
public class SendRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {


        try {

            URL url = new URL("http://services.sweken.com/api2/information/checkRegionByPincode");

            JSONObject postDataParams = new JSONObject();



            postDataParams.put("address", ad);
            postDataParams.put("address_1", ad1);
            postDataParams.put("pincode", pos);
            postDataParams.put("land_mark", land);
            postDataParams.put("name", nameee);
            postDataParams.put("mobile_no", nameeee);


            Log.e("params", postDataParams.toString());

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds *);
                 conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();

            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                String line = "";

                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                    sb.append(line);
                    break;
                }

                in.close();
                return sb.toString();

            } else {
                return new String("false : " + responseCode);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {
            object = new JSONObject(result);
            ggg = object.getString("customer_id");
            Log.d("customer",ggg);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editt = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editt.putString("CUSTOMER_ID", ggg);
            editt.apply();


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }



}


public String getPostDataString(JSONObject params) throws Exception {

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;

    Iterator<String> itr = params.keys();

    while (itr.hasNext()) {

        String key = itr.next();
        Object value = params.get(key);

        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(key, "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(value.toString(), "UTF-8"));

    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

}

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
String idddd;
TextView text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    idddd = sharedPreferences.getString("CUSTOMER_ID", "");
    text.setText(idddd);
}
```

}

Comment: Can you reduce this to something that fits in a screen? Please see [mcve].

Comment: I have kept the complete code because i want to know where the problem lies please help thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem, you execute your network calls when the button is clicked, and **new intent is directly started without waiting for network call's response, so it will not work for the first time**.

Solution is to chain the operation in the Submit button's onClick validation stuff.

To chain the operations, extract this code block like this,

```
public void goToNextActivity(){
    nameee = name.getText().toString().trim();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name.getText().toString())) {


            return;


        }
        ad = addresssss.getText().toString();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(addresssss.getText().toString())) {


            return;

        }
        ad1 = address1111.getText().toString();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(address1111.getText().toString())) {


            return;

        }
        ci = city.getText().toString();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(city.getText().toString())) {


            return;

        }
        sta = state.getText().toString();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(state.getText().toString())) {


            return;

        }
        cou = country.getText().toString();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(country.getText().toString())) {


            return;

        }
       pos = postalcode.getText().toString();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(postalcode.getText().toString())) {


            return;

        }
        land = landmark.getText().toString().trim();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(landmark.getText().toString())) {


            return;

        }
        nameeee=mobiles.getText().toString().trim();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mobiles.getText().toString())) {


            return;

        }
        else {


            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
}
```

then call this method from asynctask's protected void onPostExecute(String result).

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    try {
        object = new JSONObject(result);
        ggg = object.getString("customer_id");
        Log.d("customer",ggg);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editt = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editt.putString("CUSTOMER_ID", ggg);
        editt.apply();

       //**after all needed data is persisted to preferences.**
       goToNextActivity();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you for replying i have done exactly the same but it didn't helped me it's still the same ..:(

Comment: Did you delete extracted code if not error will still happen, should be like this Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new SendRequest().execute();}});

Comment: yes i have done that i have created a separate function for form validation and i have called that function in onPostexecute() like as you said but it didn't  work